# Less than (<) sign in XSLTForms / XForms

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I'm trying to create a function that make some calculations and then load some canvas to a div, which is a part of an XForms form. In order to do that, I created a script section in the header and added some code, and I really need to compare two numbers, but the XSLTProcessor throws an error if I put the "<" sign or the "&lt" escape code... I know this is because the XML parser thinks that sign is a "opening instruction" but I don't know how to make it understand that is just a math symbol.

Comment: you should add your code snippet, and error message you receive.

Comment: I thought it was "&lt;" (note the semicolon at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the > sign. < and &lt are reserved for the XSLT processor